# LoginPage is the part of declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type LoginPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LoginPageModule! Please consider moving LoginPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and LoginPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginPage then import that NgModule in AppModule and LoginPageModule.
Error: Type LoginPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LoginPageModule! Please consider moving LoginPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and LoginPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginPage then import that NgModule in AppModule and LoginPageModule.

I am trying to build an ionic 4 application for login, everything works fine when i am running the home page of the application, but when i try to run my generated pages of login, there isn't the error in the file but the output page on the browser is blank, and when i check the console of the browser, the above error is occured.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I7tK.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk2rL.jpg)

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Show me please your appModule

Comment: A component can be declared only once. LoginPage is in declarations of LoginPage  module and AppModule.. remove it from AppModule declarations.

Comment: I have shared to codes via images link

Answer (score 1):

This is an error because you use same declaration component in 2 modules AppModule and LoginPageModule. If you need to use 2 components in different modules you can try to use sharedModule where you can add your component and import sharedModule when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared LoginPage in both LoginPageModule and AppModule. Remove it from One module.

Answer (score 1):

Go in your **app.module.ts** file and **remove LoginPage** from the declarations

Answer (score -1):

Removed the LoginPage declaration from AppModule and got the result.